# Background-size property equivalent to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Is there an equivalent to `background-size:cover` in IE pre-version 9? I have a book on CSS3 that just seems to say previous versions of IE just don't use this property and they don't give a workaround.

Comment: What are you trying to use `background-size: cover` for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good "background-size: cover" fallbacks/shims/tricks for cross-browser compatibility on DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, you could use the following (untested)

pre IE8 use -

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='linkToImage.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
```

IE8 use -

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='linkToImage.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

*Using the sizingMethod= 'scale' means that even IE will scale the background image to the size of the browser window.*

Source:
http://www.pziecina.com/design/turorial_demos/resize_background.php

Comment: Kinda works, but it's worth explicitly noting that this won't maintain the aspect ratio of the image.