# IE7, CSS3, background images & scaling

Tags: image, css, internet-explorer-7, scaling

Ok, so here's my problem.
For a client I'm using a lightbox (in this case slimbox2)
I've modified it's contents so that if the images are larger than the screensize,
the image max width/height is the screensize itself.

So in other words: **if image > screensize => image == screensize**

I'm using css3 background-size property for most browsers wich works just fine.
And for IE5.5+ I'm using the **filter: AlphaImageLoader**.

All this is good, but when I hover on the image I should get a next and previous button.
This does not work in IE7- It seems the buttons stay under the background image because
it has the **css filter: AlphaImageLoader** on it. Is there any way to make
the buttons visible?

Here's a piece of my code **(JQUERY MERGED WITH PHP):**

```
        $bgsize = preload.width +'px '+preload.height +'px';
        $(image).css({backgroundImage: "url(" + activeURL + ")",
                          visibility: "hidden",
                          display: "block",
                          'background-size':$bgsize,
                          '-webkit-background-size':$bgsize,
    'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=\''+ activeURL+'\',sizingMethod=\'scale\')',
'-ms-filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=\''+ activeURL+'\',sizingMethod=\'scale\'
```

Here's the css:

```
#lbImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#lbPrevLink, #lbNextLink {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:-10px;
    width: 50%;
    outline: none;
}

#lbPrevLink {
    left: 0;
}

#lbPrevLink:hover {
    background: url(prevlabel.jpg) no-repeat 0 15%;
}

#lbNextLink {
    right: 0;
        z-index:20000;
}

#lbNextLink:hover {
    background: transparent url(nextlabel.jpg) no-repeat 100% 15%;
}
```

**PS: tried the most common solutions like z-index, positioning relative/absolute, etc..**

Comment: Are the buttons `<a>` tags? I do know that for ie7, if you want block type buttons, they have to have a non-transparent background color or a background image set in order for them to work properly, especially if they don't contain text.

Try adding `background-image: url('nonexistantimage.jpg');` to `#lbPrevLink, #lbNextLink`. Non-existing images work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlphaImageLoader puts an image between the object background and content, so everything underneath is [obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847). Use a [background-size shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi/9693100#9693100) or a [pure CSS lightbox](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplayBox.html) as an alternative.

Comment: I made it work by customizing the code completely so that when it was bigger than my screen, it would rescale to screensize