# How to constrain large images (for retina) in html table-based emails?

Tags: image, css, mailchimp

My website uses very large images so we can optimize for retina devices. In my WordPress site we produce 1200x640 images and constrain the size of them to be 600x320 within the theme template.

```
For example: <img src="image/path" width="600" height="320" />
```

As a result, my RSS feed contains large images (1200x640) and when we go to use them in our MailChimp template within RSS Feedblocks, the images blow out the size of the table cell. Is there anyway to wrap this MailChimp feedblock tag with a span tag and set a max-width? We are looking constrain the image size to (600x320) within the MailChimp newsletter template without having to alter the RSS feed. Is this possible?

```
*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*
```

Comment: I wouldn't use images of that file size in an email. Would take a lot longer to load. And who knows how some mail clients will render them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good "background-size: cover" fallbacks/shims/tricks for cross-browser compatibility on DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi)

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same in many newsletters and advise against the comments above (few mail clients support 'background-size: cover' well, if at all.

The technique that has seemed to work best for us is to keep your table cells at whatever their width but then in the style attribute of the image itself set a max-width: 100%. This has it honor the maximum width of its parent rather than its 'natural' image size. If you can't edit the image tag itself, finding its class and adding the style max-width in your newsletter's style should also work pretty well.