# IE CSS Background Image Work Around

Tags: internet-explorer, css, browser

Below is my CSS code for my logo at the top of the page that resizes its self to the users device size in all browser apart from IE8 and below it appears to work just fine constraining the original proportions of the logo however IE8 and below appears to ignore the constrain proportions and stretch the image to the maximum dimensions e.g. 90% screen width. What is some legacy / fall back code for IE to prevent this behaviour from occurring ?

Note: I need the current margins and height percentages if possible as allows the logo to be central and appropriately proportioned for most devices. e.g. I don't want a fixed width

CSS CODE

```
#logo-bounding-box {
      background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
      background-size: contain;
      position:relative;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin:0 auto 0 auto;
      background-position:center;
      height: 90%;
      width: 90%;
    }
```

Comment: while you are talking about 90% its assuming parent's 90%, irrespective of height/width, so better make it like this min-height:90%; height:200px !important;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good "background-size: cover" fallbacks/shims/tricks for cross-browser compatibility on DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly better to not use the image as a background image.

Just place it as a normal img tag on the page - probably within a DIV.

```
<div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt=""></div>

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Although this didn't solve my issue completely I used this code and Media queries to resize my logo so you can have the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The background-size: contain/cover rules are not present lt-ie9 so you need to use some fallback. There is some ie filter which could work:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/logo.gif', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/logo.gif', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Or you could try out this https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js

Or just use an img element set to stretch to its container, as suggested before.