# Background-size workaround for lte IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I just realised that IE7/8 [don't support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) the background-size property.

It's very common for me to use:

```
.image{
    background-size:100% auto; /* in case browser doesn't support the :cover value. */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But what's the way to go when IE 7 or 8?

-EDIT-

I Would like to apply it to multiple images.. something like:

```
<ul>
 <li class="image" style="background-image:url('path/to/img1');"></li>
 <li class="image" style="background-image:url('path/to/img2');"></li>
 <li class="image" style="background-image:url('path/to/img3');"></li>
 <li class="image" style="background-image:url('path/to/img4');"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good "background-size: cover" fallbacks/shims/tricks for cross-browser compatibility on DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many other ways to go around. Check [this source](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and choose which you prefer.

Comment: But most of them use an image to achieve it... i want to apply size to a background image

Comment: no... i need to apply it to a list of images... that's why the fixed solution won't apply...